# Name of the model in memory that you use for map collision detection?

Tags: collision-detection, maps, terminology

I'm trying to remember the English name for a memory model of a map built exclusively for handling collision detection. I think this is especially frequent in tile-based platform games.

I believe the Spanish term for it is "Mapa de durezas".

If you have a *Super Mario* tilemap like this:

```
    C     +        'P' = Pipe
         +++       '+' = Brick
        +++++      '@' = Ground
   P   +++++++     'C' = Cloud
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  ' ' = Air
```

Then the `<ENGLISH EXPRESSION THAT I'M LOOKING FOR>` of that map would be:

```
          *       '*' = Solid
         ***      ' ' = Traversable
        *****     
   *   *******
 ****************
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term you are looking for may be "collision map".

Comment: I was about to answer 'collision layer', then realised it's the same as this.

Comment: For future reference, a more common term IMO is a Collision Hull.